# Why won't this slideshow code work?

Tags: javascript

```
<img id="slideshow" src="4.png" alt="image" width="264" height="264"/>
<script>
    source=["1.jpg", "2.JPG", "3.JPG"];
    for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("slideshow").src = source[i];
    }
</script>
```

Don't quite understand why this doesn't work, I realise this will stop on the image, well I think so at least lol, but it doesn't show any image.

Any help would be great thanks.

```
            <img id="slideshow" src="4.png" alt="image" width="264" height="264"/>
            <script>
            source=["1.jpg", "2.JPG", "3.JPG"];
            var i=0;
            var c=0;
            while (i<=0)
            {
            if (c<source.length)
            document.getElementById("slideshow").src = source[c];
            c++;
            else
            c=0;
            }
            </script>
```

any ideas how to get it to stop on each source and then repeat?

Comment: This one was actually a bit trickier (if you did not expect a typo) because it does not throw an error. Though you could have noticed then that the loop body is not executed and hence checked the loop condition and then discover the typo.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code:

```
for (var i=0; i<source.lenth; i++)
                       ~~~~~
                       ^
```

it should be `length` not `lenth`.

Comment: god I even checked for typos lol, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the browser executes pieces of JavaScript without re-rendering the page. So you actually change the src, but browser doesn't show any animation, because it just shows the state when it ends.

To create animations, window.setTimeout() is used.

Instead of a loop (`for`, `while` and such), you change the `src` in a function, and then use `window.setTimeout()` to call the same function.

Like,

```
var num = 0;

function foo(){
    num = ++num % 4;
    document.getElementById("image").src = "image"+num+".jpg"
    window.setTimeout("foo()", 300);
}
```

Tips:

1. Try jQuery and libs built on top of it.
2. Install Firebug plugin in Firefox and debug the Javascript to see what's going on.