# Why won't this slideshow work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, slideshow

Okay, What I'm trying to do is create a slide show using this example below. The problem is the animation does not work. Design wise it looks good but images will not rotate in my browser. Is it because I have to use window.setTimeout() Thanks!

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/

also someone seems to be having a similar problem but not quite the same code as mine:

[Why won't this slideshow code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226104/why-wont-this-slideshow-code-work)

Heres the HTML:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>An HTML5 Slideshow w/ Canvas & jQuery | Tutorialzine Demo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="slideshow">

        <ul class="slides">
            <li><img src="img/photos/1.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Marsa Alam" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/photos/2.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Turrimetta Beach" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/photos/3.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Power Station" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/photos/4.jpg" width="620" height="320" alt="Colors of Nature" /></li>
        </ul>

        <span class="arrow previous"></span>
        <span class="arrow next"></span>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Then here we have the CSS:

```
#slideshow{
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height:340px;
    margin:150px auto 0;
    position:relative;
    width:640px;

    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 22px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 22px #111;
    box-shadow:0 0 22px #111;
}

#slideshow ul{
    height:320px;
    left:10px;
    list-style:none outside none;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    width:620px;
}

#slideshow li{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow li:first-child{
    display:block;
    z-index:1000;
}

#slideshow .slideActive{
    z-index:1000;
}

#slideshow canvas{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}

#slideshow .arrow{
    height:86px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    background:url('img/arrows.png') no-repeat;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-43px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:5000;
}

#slideshow .previous{ background-position:left top;left:0;}
#slideshow .previous:hover{ background-position:left bottom;}

#slideshow .next{ background-position:right top;right:0;}
#slideshow .next:hover{ background-position:right bottom;}
```

---

And now the javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    // We are listening to the window.load event, so we can be sure
    // that the images in the slideshow are loaded properly.

    // Testing wether the current browser supports the canvas element:
    var supportCanvas = 'getContext' in document.createElement('canvas');

    // The canvas manipulations of the images are CPU intensive,
    // this is why we are using setTimeout to make them asynchronous
    // and improve the responsiveness of the page.

    var slides = $('#slideshow li'),
        current = 0,
        slideshow = {width:0,height:0};

    setTimeout(function(){

        if(supportCanvas){
            $('#slideshow img').each(function(){

                if(!slideshow.width){
                    // Saving the dimensions of the first image:
                    slideshow.width = this.width;
                    slideshow.height = this.height;
                }

                // Rendering the modified versions of the images:
                createCanvasOverlay(this);
            });
        }

        $('#slideshow .arrow').click(function(){
            var li            = slides.eq(current),
                canvas        = li.find('canvas'),
                nextIndex    = 0;

            // Depending on whether this is the next or previous
            // arrow, calculate the index of the next slide accordingly.

            if($(this).hasClass('next')){
                nextIndex = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
            }
            else {
                nextIndex = current <= 0 ? slides.length-1 : current-1;
            }

            var next = slides.eq(nextIndex);

            if(supportCanvas){

                // This browser supports canvas, fade it into view:

                canvas.fadeIn(function(){

                    // Show the next slide below the current one:
                    next.show();
                    current = nextIndex;

                    // Fade the current slide out of view:
                    li.fadeOut(function(){
                        li.removeClass('slideActive');
                        canvas.hide();
                        next.addClass('slideActive');
                    });
                });
            }
            else {

                // This browser does not support canvas.
                // Use the plain version of the slideshow.

                current=nextIndex;
                next.addClass('slideActive').show();
                li.removeClass('slideActive').hide();
            }
        });

    },100);

// This function takes an image and renders
    // a version of it similar to the Overlay blending
    // mode in Photoshop.

    function createCanvasOverlay(image){

        var canvas            = document.createElement('canvas'),
            canvasContext    = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Make it the same size as the image
        canvas.width = slideshow.width;
        canvas.height = slideshow.height;

        // Drawing the default version of the image on the canvas:
        canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);

        // Taking the image data and storing it in the imageData array:
        var imageData    = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height),
            data        = imageData.data;

        // Loop through all the pixels in the imageData array, and modify
        // the red, green, and blue color values.

        for(var i = 0,z=data.length;i<z;i++){

            // The values for red, green and blue are consecutive elements
            // in the imageData array. We modify the three of them at once:

            data[i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2*data[i]*data[i] / 255) :
                        (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));
            data[++i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2*data[i]*data[i] / 255) :
                        (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));
            data[++i] = ((data[i] < 128) ? (2*data[i]*data[i] / 255) :
                        (255 - 2 * (255 - data[i]) * (255 - data[i]) / 255));

            // After the RGB channels comes the alpha value, which we leave the same.
            ++i;
        }

        // Putting the modified imageData back on the canvas.
        canvasContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0,0,0,imageData.width,imageData.height);

        // Inserting the canvas in the DOM, before the image:
        image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas,image);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can create jsfiddle with `html`, `css` ? Does requirement include utilizing existing `js` ?

Comment: No idea  how to creat a slideshow in CSS. My understanding was it was a script according on how to do it on this [Tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/).

Also it has been brought to my attention that googleapis is down right now so it might not be working because of that.

Comment: Should still be able to try/run, (if working) by downloading `jquery` http://code.jquery.com, then placing jquery in same folder, adjusting that particular `script` `src` to the version of `jquery` downloaded, i.e.g., `src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"`

Comment: sorry bit of a beginner at this but how do I adjust the script src to my version of jquery. I put Jquery 2.1.0 in my folder.

Comment: No worries. Open `html` page in text editor, substitute `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` for `<script src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>`. To try locally (not online), open browser, open the `html` page that just edited. To make certain `jquery` loaded, open `console` at browser of `html` page, type `typeof window.jQuery === "function"`, if return `true`, jQuery loaded at html page. Hopefully `slideshow` work ok then. If not, please post, happy to help if able

Answer (score 0):

FYI google's cnd is down at the moment: http://www.websitedown.info/ajax.googleapis.com, so jquery might not be loading.

[image: google's cnd results]