# Testing Jquery links outside of Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there another way to check a jquery link besides inspect element in google chrome?  I've done that, and thought that was the issue as it failed to load the links, but I corrected it and it still won't do what I'm telling it to do, specifically the show function won't do the animations I'm specifying.  The hide works just fine, though, and the rotating text works as well.  I'm having so CSS or javascript issues, so the only thing I can think is that I've mucked up my jquery links and I haven't the foggiest idea what I've done.

HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE><HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Mary</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link href="C://wamp/www/Projects/Resume/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="C://wamp/www/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/Mary/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C://wamp/www/Projects/Resume/jscript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C://wamp/www/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><small></small></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Andale Mono"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li style="font-family:fantasy"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li style="font-family: Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><mark></mark></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 
</div>


<div id="background">
            <div class="col1">text              
            </div>
            <div class="col1">text  
            </div>  
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col2">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <ol>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ol>   
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col3">
                <ol>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col3">

            </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS is:

```
#content {
    background-color: #030505;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#list{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#list ul, #list li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#list a{
    position:absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444444;
}
#list a:hover{
    color: #EB7500;
}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: A3D8F4;
}

.col1 {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: dotted;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

.col2{
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

.col3{
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $('#list a');
    var offset = 0;
    var stepping = 0.03;
    var list = $('#list');
    var $list = $(list);
        $list.mousemove(function (e) {
            var topOfList = $list.eq(0).offset().top;
            var listHeight = $list.height();
            stepping = (e.clientY - topOfList) / listHeight * 0.2 - 0.1;
});
for (var i = element.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    element[i].elemAngle = i * Math.PI * 2 / element.length;
        }
    setInterval(render, 30);
function render() {
    for (var i = element.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var angle = element[i].elemAngle + offset;
            x = 120 + Math.sin(angle) * 10;
            y = 45 + Math.cos(angle) * 40;
            size = Math.round(40 - Math.sin(angle) * 20);
                var elementCenter = $(element[i]).width() / 2;
                var leftValue = (($list.width() / 2) * x / 100 - elementCenter) + "px"
                    $(element[i]).css("fontSize", size + "pt");
                    $(element[i]).css("opacity", size / 100);
                    $(element[i]).css("zIndex", size);
                    $(element[i]).css("left", leftValue);
                    $(element[i]).css("top", y + "%");
                }
                offset += stepping;
            }
});

$(function(){
    $('#content').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#background').show();
    });
});
```

Prior to fixing a different issue I had with my links (I was referencing the wrong CSS link), the jquery worked fine! I was experimenting with all of the show options.  I'm not sure what's going on now, I'm hoping it's just some link error that I'm not able to find in the inspect element part or there is some other best practice someone might know that can help me fix this and avoid this problem in the future.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/22867166/2801559

Comment: that was it, thanks so much!  And it's still not working!  I never even thought that it could be the API.  How long are they usually down for?

Comment: Not certain. Perhaps try http://code.jquery.com or possibly save files to folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You're linking Jquery-ui min after your jscript.js. You might want to put it before the jscript.js. That could solve the issue.